# Is it a hiragana or a kanji or something else entirely?

Tags: hiragana, contractions

This is the description of the Japanese book 告白 by Kanae Minato. In the picture, in red, are two instances of a character I suppose to be a hiragana.

But I have never seen it and can't find it anywhere on the internet.

[image]

Through context I think it might be a contracted form of ここ, but is there even such a thing as contracting two hiragana in one? How do we call it so I can find more info of that on the internet?

I will very much appreciate if you guys could enlighten me on the meaning of it.

Comment: I have just remembered about 〆切 that represents a contraction of 締め, and it led me to this page below. Would this be, in the image, the top character in the one highlighted in red? Did I really get it right that it means ここ?  https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%9D#Japanese

Comment: I tried to find this description on Amazon Japan... And found it... It is a と! But how on earth is this a と?  ➡️➡️➡️ 語り手が「級友」「犯人」「犯人の家族」と次々と変わり、次第に事件の全体像が浮き彫りにされていく。

Comment: と originates from the kanji 止. If you investigate how this is written in cursive (草書), you will see how this might be a valid way to write the kana.

Comment: I think the を on the third (full) line which traces the same curve in its lower right should be a good clue as to what character this turns out to be.

Answer (score 10):

It's a cursive version of と like the one in the picture, but written more stylistically

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This style of と is found in fonts like 築地体初号仮名, an archaic looking font developed by Morisawa. It's a reproduction of a particular set of movable type, and other font makers might have similar looking ones, but Morisawa's particularly looks similar to me.

Here is a sample [provided by Morisawa](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1861):
[image: 築地体初号仮名]

So what you have found is not an instance of hiragana contractions and shorthands. If you are looking for them, they are called kana ligatures (合略仮名). [ゟ for より](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%9F) is one of them.

Answer (score 8):

It is not a contraction but a design of と. It is supposed to represent the beginning of the stroke written with a brush.

You can see the same style in し in 亡くした on the fourth line. On this, the following contains more information.

- [ひらがな書体の種類と移り変わり](https://crd.ndl.go.jp/reference/modules/d3ndlcrdentry/index.php?page=ref_view&id=1000141302)

---

The closest I can find is a font named [GL-築地五号](https://www.fontmatome.com/gl-tsukiji-5/)

[image: to]

---

For a similar thing in Latin alphabets, you can think about the difference between **a** and ***a***, or between modern scripts and [uncial scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncial_script).